# Text to Json Convert

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to convert some number of data to json. here is the formate.

**Here is the Text data**

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
```

**want to convert this type of json data**

```js
{
    "0":"192.168.0.1",
    "1":"192.168.0.2",
    "2":"192.168.0.3",
    "3":"192.168.0.4",
    "4":"192.168.0.5",
    "5":"192.168.0.6",
    "6":"192.168.0.7",
    "8":"192.168.0.8",
    "10":"192.168.0.9",
}
```

Please help me :)

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your _"text data_" stored? Is it in a file or in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *"text data"* is in a variable, you can turn it into an array using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.explode.php) and then encode it as a JSON object using [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php) with the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag

```php
$textData = <<<_TEXT
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
_TEXT;

$json = json_encode(explode(PHP_EOL, $textData), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/BrOSK

---

If your data is in a file, use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.file.php) to read it into an array instead

```php
$json = json_encode(array_map("trim", file("data.txt")), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: `array_map('trim', file('data.txt')` to remove `\n` at the end

Comment: @swadhwa nice one. I always forget that `file` keeps the delimiters